# Changing the structure of a data frame from vertical way to horizontal

Tags: r, dataframe, data-structures

I have a dataframe (db) as follows:

STUDENT_ID / DESCRIPTION / TERM /  ACH /  MID / FINAL

STUDENT_ID  is the student number

DESCRIPTION  is the subject name

TERM  is the term when the student studied the subject

ACH   is the mark of achievements in that subject

MID   is the mark of midterm in that subject

FINAL   is the mark of final in that subject

I want to create a new dataframe with a new structure as follows

[Empty dataframe created(d)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv47n.png)

So I want to fill (d) with the data from (db)

student_no = STUDENT_NO

term = TERM

ach_m = ACH (where DESCRIPTION = MATHEMATICS)

mid_m = MID (where DESCRIPTION = MATHEMATICS)

final_m = FINAL (where DESCRIPTION = MATHEMATICS)

and so on for each subject .... while it was each row for a subject in different term in (db), in (d)

There will be only one row per term that filled with all subjects marks.

So a total of 6 records per student as the student studied 6 terms.

This is the code I tried. It takes a loooong time to excute and the result coping Similar values of a column in 10 thousands or more rows but the good thing it is in the correct columns (student_id , term ) and maybe start to fill one subject for example ((ach_m , mid_m , final_m)):

```
for (i in seq(1, nrow(db),1)) {
    for (j in seq(1, nrow(d),1)) {
        if (str_detect(db[i,2] , "Arabic ") == TRUE) {
            d[j,1]  <- db[i,1]
            d[j,2]  <- db[i,3]
            d[j,15] <- db[i,4]
            d[j,16] <- db[i,5]
            d[j,17] <- db[i,6]
        }
        if (str_detect(db[i,2], "English ") == TRUE) {
            d[j,1]  <- db[i,1]
            d[j,2]  <- db[i,3]
            d[j,18] <- db[i,4]
            d[j,19] <- db[i,5]
            d[j,20] <- db[i,6]
        }
        if (str_detect(db[i,2], "Physics ") == TRUE) {
            d[j,1]  <- db[i,1]
            d[j,2]  <- db[i,3]
            d[j,12] <- db[i,4]
            d[j,13] <- db[i,5]
            d[j,14] <- db[i,6]
        }
        if (str_detect(db[i,2], "Chemistry ") == TRUE) {
            d[j,1] <- db[i,1]
            d[j,2] <- db[i,3]
            d[j,6] <- db[i,4]
            d[j,7] <- db[i,5]
            d[j,8] <- db[i,6]
        }
        if (str_detect(db[i,2], "Biology ") == TRUE) {
            d[j,1]  <- db[i,1]
            d[j,2]  <- db[i,3]
            d[j,9]  <- db[i,4]
            d[j,10] <- db[i,5]
            d[j,11] <- db[i,6]
        }
        if (str_detect(db[i,2], "Mathmatics.* ") == TRUE) {
            d[j,1] <- db[i,1]
            d[j,2] <- db[i,3]
            d[j,3] <- db[i,4]
            d[j,4] <- db[i,5]
            d[j,5] <- db[i,6]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the `tidyr` package, in particular `pivot_wide` or its predecessor `spread`

Comment: I will try it now .. I hope it will work it out